# Mongoose: find document by values inside an array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a chat schema that looks like that:

```js
var chatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    users: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    }]
});
```

It contains array of user IDs.
Now I want to find one chat document that contains an array of two user IDs.

At the beginning I tried to do this:

```js
Chat.findOne({ users: { $in: [req.user_id, receiver._id] }})
    .then(chat => { })
```

But it seems that every time it gives me the chat that contains at least one of the IDs I mentioned in the query.

So I've tried to change it to this but with no luck:

```js
Chat.findOne()
    .where({ users: { $in: [req.user_id] }})
    .where({ users: { $in: [receiver._id] }})
    .then(chat => { })
```

I need to find the chat that contains both of the user ID's inside the users array otherwise I expect for a null value.

How can I achieve this goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way `$in` works - returns the document when at least one value matches. You should use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) instead:

```
Chat.findOne({ users: { $all: [req.user_id, receiver._id] }})
```